# Select table in Mechanize (ruby)

Tags: ruby, parsing, select, html-table, mechanize

I try with my internet-bot to get infos from a table on a website.
The table has just "map_table" as id (CSS attribute) tr has "map_tr" and for a cell it's "map_td".

I want to detect the cells with a link containing "msg.php" in their href.
Ex :

```
<td id="map_td">
<a href="index.php"></a>
</td>
```

This one has not to be selected

```
<td id="map_td">
<a href="msg.php?id=1392"></a>
</td>
```

This one has to be selected. I have searched in the Mechanize doc, in forums, I haven't found anything.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
page.search('td:has(a[href*="msg.php"])')
```

It's the Nokogiri docs that you want look at, but really, the CSS or XPath specs if you're not familiar with either of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found what I were looking for :
`if(agent.page.search('#map_table').at('#map_td').at('a')['href'].index('msg.php')){
#DO SOMETHING
}`